# Setting UIImage on a UIImageView Takes a long time

Tags: arrays, multithreading, uiimageview, uiimage

I am generating QRCode using this code

```
func generateQRCode(from string: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
            
            if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
                filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
                
                guard let qrImage = filter.outputImage else {
                    completion(UIImage(named: "default")!);
                    return;
                }
                
                let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)
                completion(UIImage(ciImage: qrImage.transformed(by: transform)));
                return;
            }
            completion(UIImage(named: "default")!)
        }
    }
```

The generation process performs on background thread (`DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)`).
But when completion get called, just one line of setting image to imageView takes about 0.7 Second and because it is manipulating the view, so it must be done on MainThread.

Here is the code to set the result:

```
qrCodeImage.generateQRCode(from: "Simple Text") { image in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        self.qrCodeImage.image = image;            
        print("Spent time: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime)");
    }
}
```

just the SINGLE line in above closure takes 0.7 second.

Comment: How are you evaluating the elapsed time? And, your code doesn't show setting `.image` on the main thread?

Comment: @DonMag i update my question. I'm calculating execution time using CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

Comment: Presumably, since you are generating your QR code image on a background thread, you have a lot of other processes going on in your app. I imagine that could make it very difficult to accurately track the time. Is this representative of what you're doing? https://pastebin.com/S1XJ6gwL ... if so, I get *very* short elapsed times when running that (particularly tapping and running the test more than once).

Comment: @DonMag I updated my question so you can figure out how I calculate the time.

Comment: Your code has: `qrCodeImage.generateQRCode(...)` --- have you subclassed `UIImageView`? Or is your `func generateQRCode(...)` in an extension?

Comment: @DonMag It is in an extension. The Function in the extension is shown at the beginning of the question.

Comment: I have to assume there is an issue with some of your other code. I edited my paste at https://pastebin.com/S1XJ6gwL to use your func in a `UIImageView` extension. Each time the button is tapped it processes 1 of 3 different test strings to generate the QR Code image. Results are at the bottom (for 2 physical devices and one simulator). Try that example (on its own) and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: @DonMag I copied your code and run it. This is the output.

elapsed time to generate image: 0.882058
elapsed time from generate to async execution: 0.000311
elapsed time to set imageView.image: 0.38381
overall elapsed time: 1.266179

I ran on real device, iPhone Xs, iOS 13.7

Comment: Did you implement that code in ***your*** app? Or did you run it as a new, stand-alone app? Because I've run it on several devices, and the **longest** overall time was `0.831357` on an old, 2013 iPad Air - and that was only on the first button tap. Subsequent taps are all ***under*** `0.02` seconds.

Comment: @DonMag No i implemented it in my own app.

Comment: OK - as I said way back... *"Presumably, since you are generating your QR code image on a background thread, you have a lot of other processes going on in your app."* Clearly, the problem is ***NOT*** related to setting the `.image` property of your image view. What you need to do is figure out what your *other* code is doing that's taking up processor time.